# Globally turn off autocomplete on material's matInput

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way for globally turning off the autocomplete behaviour on material's `MatInput` fields? I would like to get rid of this boiler plate code repeating all over the place:

```html
<input matInput formControlName="myCtrl" autocomplete="off" />
```

E.g. in a similar way like globally defining the appearance and label options of the form fields with injection tokens in the app module's provider array:

```js
// Default appearance of material form fields
{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' } },
// Globally disable label of material form fields
{ provide: MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: { float: 'never' } }
```

I scanned through doc and source code and could not find anything.

Comment: I don't think there is such option. There's a `MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` token, but no option to disable it. You can try with a global script

Comment: This was my apprehension. Do you have any source for such a global script hack?

Comment: Can we use `autocomplete="off"` to the `form` tag instead of adding it to all input elements ?

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late, but maybe will be helpful.

You can just add this simple directive:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Attribute } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matInput]',
})
export class AutocompleteOffDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.autocomplete') auto;
  constructor(@Attribute('autocomplete') autocomplete: string) {
    this.auto = autocomplete || 'off'
  }

}
```

If you choose to override the autocomplete attribute it will take the text from the element.

Comment: remember to add this directive to app.module.ts or some other module to enable it

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, if there is not a better solution, you can add a global script that sets `autocomplete="off"` to all of your matInput elements.

For example, you can add this snippet in your `polyfills.ts` file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[matInput]'))
    .forEach(element => {
      element.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    });

});
```

Note: consider converting arrow functions to plain functions in order to support also IE11

Comment: The listener won't get fired when the DOM changes. I gave a try with `MutationObserver`, but it will really kill any performance as it gets almost endlessly fired when I do watch body for changes... so, I think it is not worth the hassle.

Comment: @sl3dg3 you are right, this doesn't consider the `*ngIf` stuff